# Как напечатать русский символ с помощью Java?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Недавно все-таки придумал, как вводить текст *автоматизированно* через **Robot**.
Проблема вот в чем:
**латинские** символы вводятся замечательно через метод [robot.keyPress()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress-int-), в который мы передаём код символа, определяя его с помощью [getExtendedKeyCodeForChar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(int)).
Однако, если передать туда **русский** символ, мы получим **exception**:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
```

Как можно исправить такое? Возможно есть таблицы(константы) русских кодов?

Comment: Думаю, нужно сначала переключить раскладку, после чего отправлять соответствующие нужным клавишам изначальные keyCode(английские)

Comment: @vp_arth или я что-то не так сказал/понял или Вы. Поясню. Я даю на вход текст, а робот его печатает за пару секунд в активное окно. Так вот русские символы он печатать не хочет, в отличие от латинских. P.s. Текст - просто копипаста с сайта.

Comment: Робот не текст печатает, а кнопочки нажимает. А на клавиатуре нет русских кнопочек, только английские. Нужно найти способ менять раскладку и определять её для текущего символа. Можно ещё (платформозависимо) на Windows через `AltGr+код` вводить Unicode

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо :) Изначально видимо не совсем правильно понял. Пойду пробовать.

Comment: Почему-то с помощью AltGr не выходит. Возможно, не так получаю код (но по-другому нормально и никак вроде). Вот так получаю для символа KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(i)